# fatal: '/myorg/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, ssh

I'm getting this error when trying to clone a git repository:

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ git clone git+ssh://git@gitmachine/myorg/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
fatal: '/myorg/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know the repository exists because this command works:

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ git clone git@gitmachine:myorg/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 2986, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  88% (1972/2238)
....
```

I think the problem is that the first command is making git search for the repo `/myorg/myrepo` instead of `myorg/myrepo` because if I add that extra `/` to the second command, it stops working and shows exactly the same error message that the first one:

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ git clone git@gitmachine:/myorg/myrepo
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
fatal: '/myorg/myrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I use the SSH syntax with this repository?

(The reason I think I need the SSH syntax is because I'm trying to setup port forwarding with GIT)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to specify the actual path on disk to the repository if you use SSH.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the problem. I put the full path and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work with relative paths from `git` home directory:

```
git clone git+ssh://git@gitmachine:myorg/myrepo
```

or

```
git clone git+ssh://git@gitmachine/~git/myorg/myrepo
```

By there putting absolute path you will not break anything.

### For more information

you can discuss manual page for `git-clone(1)`:

> #### GIT URLS
>
> In general, URLs contain information about the transport protocol, the address of the remote server, and the path to the repository. Depending on the transport protocol, some of this information may be absent.
>
> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching and rsync can be used for fetching and pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use them).
>
> The native transport (i.e. git:// URL) does no authentication and should be used with caution on unsecured networks.
>
> The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
> - `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/` <--
> - `git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/`
>
> An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
>
> - `[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/` <--
>
> This syntax is only recognized if there are no slashes before the first colon. This helps differentiate a local path that contains a colon. For example the local path foo:bar could be specified as an absolute path or ./foo:bar to avoid being misinterpreted as an ssh url.
>
> The ssh and git protocols additionally support ~username expansion:
>
> - `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/**` <--
> - `git://host.xz[:port]/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/`
> - `[user@]host.xz:/~[user]/path/to/repo.git/`

Comment: Aren't you mixing the SSH and GIT syntaxes there? If SSH is involved then after the `:` it will expect the port number, not the path (that is the GIT syntax)

Comment: ssh itself doesn't accept syntax `hostname:port`, but `git clone` does. Correct possibilities are in manual page for `git-clone`. See modified answer.